# Microsoft Hash DoS security update imposes 1000 form field limit, breaks large forms. How should we refactor?

Tags: asp.net, security, patch

The newly release (Dec. 29th) Microsoft security update which addresses the "hash DoS" attack vulnerabilities imposes a limit of 1000 form parameters. Unfortunately this limit breaks "very large" forms (e.g. list of items with action links, e.g. 200 items with 5 checkboxes = 1000 form fields). I agree such large pages are not very common, nor ideally usable but they do exist (sometimes for good reason) and are rendered un-functional by the new patch.

Good info about the vulnrability/microsoft patch can be found here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/12/28/asp-net-security-update-shipping-thursday-dec-29th.aspx

and

http://www.troyhunt.com/2011/12/has-hash-dos-patch-been-installed-on.html

Does anyone have ideas for how to efficiently convert legacy ASP.NET form pages, with >1000 form fields, to function on a patched system? (Aside from artificially limiting the "page size" to contain < 1000 fields)?

Comment: "legacy ASP.NET form pages, with >1000 form fields" - *shudder!*

Comment: Are forms with 1000 fields not already broken? Sounds like Microsoft is doing the users a favor. Also, is this a real problem you have?

Comment: Yes, I agree, not common but it is a real problem for us. And in some scenarios 1000 fields is not so large, e.g. a Grid of 20+ data fields by 50 rows (i.e. states) is 1000 fields and is a real implementation that results in a very real, usable UX.

Comment: "Some scenarios." Not good enough! Post the *actual scenario* of the problem that needs to be solved. We cannot solve nebulously defined problems, because those problems have many forms, and therefore many valid answers. Post the specific problem that has to be solved, we cannot simply solve all UI problems in a single question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I heard back from Scott Guthrie with some informations that makes this a non-issue:

> Friday, December 30, 2011 11:15 PM by ScottGu Pedro/PSmo,
>
> The newly released security update which addresses imposes a limit of
>   1000 form parameters.

Correct - once the patch is applied it by default limits the number of individual form fields to be 1000 per HTTP post.  This is well below any type of DoS threashold, and we felt was large enough for all but a few applications.

This limit is configurable, though, and so if you do have scenarios where you need to post more than 1000 fields you can increase it.  You can do this by adding a setting into the `<appSettings>` section of the web.config file for your application and setting the value appropriately.

For example:

```
<appSettings>

  <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="some number here"/>

</appSettings>
```

We've enabled this within  so that you can set this in any application and not worry about it breaking on an un-patched server.

Hope this helps,

Scott

Comment: Upgrading to .NET 4.5 would also fix the issue - the '1000 form params' limit is removed; the underlying issue is fixed: "Hashtable and Dictionary in 4.5 use randomized hash algorithm if using StringComparer" see discussion: https://twitter.com/troyhunt/status/240583013367418881

Answer (score 1):

Would it be acceptable to impose a limit on how many are CHANGED per post?  If so you can do an ajax call that submits only the changed fields.   If that is not acceptable, create a hidden form field (yes, yet another field), use script to collect all the values to be submitted, string them together into a parseable format, stuff that into the hidden field, and submit just that hidden field.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I think your approach would work well. However, I have learned there is an AppSetting that can be used to "tune" the limit specifically for applications like ours that have some very large forms. (see my answer)